# Size of a single key in an index

Tags: sql, indexing, non-clustered-index

I have built a non-clusterd index over a few fields. How now do I view the size of each key in my index, or is this simply the sum of the field byte sizes I have used in my index?

Thanks
Thomas

Comment: The sum of the size of the columns used in your index, ***plus*** (on the leaf level) the size of the **clustering index columns** (if those have been defined on your table)

Answer (score 0):

It is in the rows in the table I do expect. If I'm correct rows always contain all data and indexes just add overhead. Since you didn't say which database you're using, results might differ somewhat.

I assumed you were doing it in SQL Server - it's got lots of information in special system views and tables of which I demonstrate a view below.

At least this query will give you total size (including row data and large object (varbinaries/images) but also some separately. I copied this so bear with me but add 
partition_stats.*, to the select list and you will get separate statistics at least for blobs and row data..you do the math)

```
SELECT 
in_row_data_page_count * 8 / 1024 RowDataSizeMB, 
in_row_used_page_count * 8 / 1024 RowSizeMB,
sys_schemas.name AS SchemaName  
,sys_objects.name AS TableName  
,sys_indexes.name AS IndexName  
,sys_indexes.type_desc AS IndexType  
,partition_stats.used_page_count * 8 AS TotalSizeKB  
,CAST(partition_stats.used_page_count * 8 / 1024.00 AS Decimal(10,3))AS TotalSizeMB  
,CAST(partition_stats.used_page_count * 8 / 1048576.00 AS Decimal(10,3)) AS TotalSizeGB  
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats partition_stats  
INNER JOIN sys.indexes sys_indexes  
ON partition_stats.[object_id] = sys_indexes.[object_id]   
AND partition_stats.index_id = sys_indexes.index_id  
AND sys_indexes.type_desc <> 'HEAP'  
INNER JOIN sys.objects sys_objects  
ON sys_objects.[object_id] = partition_stats.[object_id]   
INNER JOIN sys.schemas sys_schemas    
ON sys_objects.[schema_id] = sys_schemas.[schema_id]   
AND sys_schemas.name <> 'SYS'  
--WHERE partition_stats.[object_id] = object_id('dbo.TableName')  
ORDER BY 1,2,3,4
```

I'm not the expert though - look for example at this link for more on this, including more SQL statements...

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic404843-793-1.aspx#bm568295

Comment: Thanks, I've done something similar before. My index is 148424412 KB or 150 GB in size. However, the fields in index are of sizes int, nvarchar 100 bytes and then I include another int. This sums to 108 bytes. I have 2 billion rows, giving 216 billion bytes or 216 GB. This 216 GB should be the lower limit. I presume the nvarchar(100) is doing something sneeky. Is there any way I can accurately try and establish where the size of my index keys?